# Debug Word VSTO Add-In: Debug Word doc as though it were opened by double-clicking it in explorer

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I have a Word VSTO add-in. A tester found a bug that occurs only when the Word document is opened by double-clicking it in Windows File Explorer.

I know how to bring up Word and attach Visual Studio debugger to it afterward.

I know how to use Visual Studio debug settings to start explorer.exe as an external program and have it display its dialog with a specific docx file selected.

I can't figure out how to set up Visual Studio to attach to a Word process that will be running only after I simulate double-clicking a Word doc displayed by explorer.exe

How do I use Visual Studio debug settings to open a Word docx file as though it were double-clicked in the dialog displayed by explorer.exe and then attach to the resultant Word process?

Clarification added: I need my VS debugger to be active at the point in time when the "double-click" opens the Word doc in Word so I can debug code starting with event handlers that are fired right as the doc is opened, e.g., window activate, doc open.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Debugger.Launch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch?view=net-6.0) method which launches and attaches a debugger to the process in the code of your add-in where you would like to get the debugger to be attached. If a debugger is already attached, nothing happens.

You may find the [Attach to running processes with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022) article helpful.

Comment: On my machine that has VS and my VSTO add-in source code, in the Add-In StartUp method, I added `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()`. After that, I coded a messagebox.show() to show the value that Launch() returns. Then, I built a Release version of the VSTO add-in. Then, on the same machine, I left VS up and I set a breakpoint in the Add-In StartUp method after the messagebox.show(). Then, to test, I ran Word. The messagebox.Show() shows TRUE. However, the breakpoint was never hit, i.e., I still can't debug

Comment: You need to build the debug version to be able to start debugging. In case of release version you may find logging statements helpful.

Comment: I built both versions. I built release version because on a dev machine, the only way to get the VSTO addin installed into Word so it is there when Word is run outside of VS is to build the release version. Same result. Here are my steps: I added `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` to `ThisAddIn-Startup()`; I built the release version ann then the debug version. Set the breakpoint. Outside of VS, I run Word. My messagebox.show shows TRUE (debugger launched). I then go to VS and look at the breakpoint: Nothing. The debug version of my source code in VS is not active, breakpoint not hit

Comment: You can use it only with a debug version.

Comment: Too bad. I guess System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() is not applicable to my scenario, i.e., I need to attach my debugger to a Word process AFTER it is created, and System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() does not do that

Comment: Consider adding log statements to the code.